# HISTOGRAM (Array = Stars Output)

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

HISTOGRAM:
I have problem in my code..
The Intended Output must be something Like this:

**Output:**

```
0 8 ********  
1 6 ******   
2 3 ***  
3 7 *******
```

**But mine shows:**

```
0 8 *******************************    
1 6 *******************************
2 3 *******************************  
3 7 *******************************
```

I've searched and compare it to my code but nothing really helps me though..

Can you kindly take a look at my code and give some suggestions, and comments on

how could I code the intended output properly..

Any Help is Appreciated ...

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

             int n = 0;
            n  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));

            int[] arr = new int[n];
             String stars = "";
             int input = 0;



            for(int c = 0; c<n; c++ ){
            input  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number"));
            arr[c]=input;


             for(int i=0; i<input; i++){ 
                        stringBuilder.append("*"); 
                 }


                 }
            for(int i=0; i<input; i++){ 
                stringBuilder.append("*"); 
            }

                for (int o = 0; o<n ; o++){ 
                stars = stringBuilder.toString();
                System.out.println( o +" "+arr[o]+" "+stars);
                }



        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Can you kindly take a look at my code and give some suggestions, and comments on"* - Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Show us your code.  The answer will most likely be obvious to everyone and certainly to the @MadProgrammer .

Comment: Please ignore the 2nd and 3rd comment and go with the advice of @MadProgrammer.  I.E. don't post an uncompilable code snippet, but a [mcve].  Voting to close (for lack of MCVE).

Comment: Other tips:  1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: There is none, The ( o +" "+arr[o]+" "+stars) is a Loop that is numbered by a counter, probably o in the for loop, simply a print per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you append the `*` in the builder object, clear the previous content. You can use `stringBuilder.setLength(0)`;

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prop {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    int n = 0;
    n  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value"));

    int[] arr = new int[n];
    String stars = "";
    int input = 0;

    for(int c = 0; c<n; c++ ){
      input  = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number"));
      arr[c]=input;

      for(int i=0; i<input; i++){
        stringBuilder.append("*");
      }
      stars = stringBuilder.toString();
      System.out.println( c +" "+arr[c]+" "+stars);
      stringBuilder.setLength(0);             // Reset the `stringBuilder` once pattern is written
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 8 ********  
1 6 ******  
2 3 ***  
3 7 *******
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for small test cases, over small range.

Comment: Thank you.. 
So .setLength(0) is a Function that makes the value Zero so everytime it loops the input's equivalent asterisk will be shown..

Im laughing at myself right now for this confusion..

Its a great first Experience here in Stack Exchange.. Thank you for the Help and added information